# NextJS & CSS SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, next.js

I'm trying to unit test but the only way I can stop the error throwing is to comment out the `import './styles.css` line.

As soon as I put it back in I get:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

...

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

      1 | import React from 'react';
      2 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    > 3 | import './styles.css';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 |
```

I have webpack, babel, jest, enzyme all configured but googling tells me there's a difference between running the app (via webpack) and using .css files *vs* running tests that can read `.css` files, which would need to be configured separately.

For love nor money, I *cannot* find an example where `import './styles.css` is successfully imported & the tests pass.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you running your tests? Do you run them also using Webpack? Or even `babel-node`? The issue is Webpack understands that this code needs bundled where as if you are just trying to run tests via Node then Node won't understand that, in fact unless you have [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) enabled, it won't even understand `import`. You may need to look at something like [babel-jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest) to compile your test code before you run.

Comment: @James cheers, I've just used Create Next App then installed the same modules as exist in github / examples / with-jest https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-jest 

Just trying Babel-Jest now.  I love NextJS for its SSR but the config is such a beast 

Comment: Seems like this is a common problem https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/334
I am attempting to put conditional logic in to detect if NODE_ENV is test and if not, import the stylesheet, but this fails too because the if statement pushes the require / import down and then its `"'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"`

Comment: so just to be clear, when you remove this import your tests run as expected? Also it's worth noting the issue you are referring to is over 2 years old, and closed. Not sure how far down the thread you read but there's a [comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/334#issuecomment-220707702) from the repo maintainer who points people in the direction of babel-jest for any dynamic CSS being loaded.

Comment: @James yeah, when I comment-out the styles import everything runs fine. Trying to get `babel-jest` working (see earlier comment^ ), but even this is a tad confusing. Jest's documentation for config is light on full, useable examples. My `jest.config.js` has a `testPathIgnorePatterns` key value and calls in the `jest.setup.js` file. But babel-jest is apparently already wrapped up into jest itself, which means config changes for it aren't necessary, i'm *guessing* - maybe this leaves me with `babel-node` as a last option. 

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get this working by hitting up https://github.com/eddyerburgh/jest-transform-stub

My jest.config.js now looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'], // links to normal "configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })" stuff.

    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.next/', '<rootDir>/node_modules/'], // ignores test files in .next(js) & node modules

    transform: {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest", // anything .js is babel'd for jest to consume
      "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub" // anything style related is ignored and mapped to jest-transform-stub module
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '\\.css$': '<rootDir>/EmptyModule.js' // <-- had to pop this in the following day to get any separetly imported .css files mapped to an empty module / object. So if i try to do import 'react-style-module/styles/my-styles.css' it would fail, though 'import './styles.css' worked. Now with this mapped correctly also, everything is imported/mapped/passing successfully.
    } 
  }
```

If anyone else has other neater solutions, please let me know. x

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file set 'type' property to 'module'

```
{
"type":"module"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you declare like this:

```
import css from './styles.css'

<div className={css.test}>

</div>
```

Reference: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css